# Resampling of a DataFrame by 1 Hour in pandas gives unexpexted NaN values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, pandas-resample

## Resampling of a DataFrame by 1 Hour in pandas gives unexpected NaN values

I have a dataframe having 3 columns. *1st Column* contains **date** **( **like 2020-07-01,2020-07-01...**)**; *2nd column* contains **time ( like 00:00:00, 01:00:00...)** for one month on hourly basis and *3rd column* contains the corresponding values of a variable including some **missing rows** (i.e., missing data) in the dataframe. **Also some values in the 2nd column (time) is like 15:06:55, 16:00:01 etc**.

I want to **resample the dataframe by 1 Hour and fill NaN values only in place of the missing data**. In my case, **Resampling gives NaN values to the missing data place as well as where the time is like 15:06:55, 16:00:01 etc.** Please help me to solve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

```py
df['Date-Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[0] + df[1],format='%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')
df = df.set_index('Date-Time')   
df = df.resample('1H').fillna(method=None)
```

**This code gives **NaN values in place of missing data as well as where the time is like 15:06:55, 16:00:01, 17:00:01** etc.** I want to resample the dataframe by 1 Hour and **fill NaN** values **only in place of the missing data**. I have uploaded an image of the dataframe before resampling. Please help me to solve the issue.
Thanks in advance.[I have uploaded an image of the dataframe before resampling.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQeAK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You use the `fillna(method=None)` method to fill the missing data. So you fill it with NaN values explicitly. See the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

You can use an interpolation or fill method to fill the missing data.
e.g.:

```
df = df.resample('1H').ffill()
```

or

```
df = df.resample('1H').interpolate(method='bfill')
```

or you fill it with the `fillna()` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), if you provide `backfill`, `bfill` of `ffill` in the method-argument.

-> look at the `interpolate()` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)

Comment: All the solutions you provide does not produce the expected output.  Resampling still gives NaN values where the time is like 15:06:55, 16:00:01 etc. In the original dataframe these timesteps have specific values which is converted to NaN after resampling with all the methods you mentioned above.

Comment: So share your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Based on your code in the question, there's no other option than getting NaN values.